# UPDATE Table -You can't specify target table 'categories' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql

Write an UPDATE statement that modifies the drums category in the Categories table. This statement should change the category_name column to “Woodwinds”, and it should use the category_id to identify the row.

When I execute

```
UPDATE categories 
SET 
    category_name = 'Woodwinds'
WHERE
    category_id = (select category_id from categories where category_name='drums');
```

I got this error: Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'categories' for update in FROM clause.

I have referred to a similar post, but can't fix it. Appreciate it if anyone can help. Thanks!

Comment: Why does this need to be so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
set @category_ids = (select GROUP_CONCAT(category_id) from categories where category_name='drums' GROUP BY category_name);
UPDATE categories 
SET 
    category_name = 'Woodwinds'
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET(category_id, @category_ids)
```